# Writing txt file to disk in Airflow is not working

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been trying to write a simple text to a local `txt` file through a DAG script. Even though the task runs successfully. I cannot seem to find the file anywhere. Is it because I am using WSL on Windows?

Here is my simple script:

```
import os

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2020, 12, 5),
    "retries": 0,
}


dag = DAG(
    "simple_dag",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval="@once",
)

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id="print_file",
    bash_command='echo "pipeline" > opDE.txt',
    dag=dag)



t1
```

Comment: Where do you expect the file to land? can you try with full path

Comment: @Elad I expect it to land inside the dag folder. Am I right?

Comment: @Elad Adding the full path made it work! Thanks

Comment: make sense when airflow execute your DAG it copy the code to tmp folder and execute it from there so the output also saved in this tmp location and eventually being deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to define a path for the output file.
When Airflow execute your code it moves it to temp location and execute it from there so it does export it to that location. You can also see this from the log:

[image]

So the fix is to export to a desired path